# Change accordion button collapsed icon color in Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-icons

I am trying to change the Bootstrap 5's [accordion's "accordion-button"](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/) color when it is collapsed.

I tried below. It changes the background but not the button's icon color.

```
.accordion-button.collapsed {
    color: white;
    background: blue;
}
```

What should I do to change the down (collapsed) icon of the accordion for Bootstrap 5?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because it is a `background-image` (using the [bootstrap icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/)) that is set in the `::after` pseudo element, so change the image

#### Update - (based on OP comment)

> It replaces the icon with the image. How do I change the color of the existing image (icon)?

So use the same background-image and change the fill to `#fff`

Note that SVG URL is encoded by boostrap

```css
.accordion-button.collapsed {
  background: blue
}

.accordion-button.collapsed::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23fff'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing
        and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

I needed to do something similar. I overrode the .accordion defaults. I did not need a new icon, just a new color. (I made fill=white for both collapsed and not). But you can see that this can easily change the icon as well.

```
<style>
        .accordion {
            --bs-accordion-btn-icon: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='white'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
            --bs-accordion-btn-active-icon: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='white'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
        }
</style>
```

Comment: This is useful because while OP asked only for the down arrow, I needed both.

Comment: I had to set these vars in the `.accordion-button::after` selector. And add to them `!important` at the end. Maybe because I am _dark_ mode

Answer (score 3):

```
.accordion-button::after {background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23fff'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e"); }
```

use this and it works perfectly customizing the css to this

Comment: this works perfectly ..great post

Answer (score 2):

If you compile your own css via sass, you can set the variable $accordion-icon-active-color which will set the fill value of the SVG.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
.accordion-button:focus {
   z-index: 3;
   border-color: #279C88;
   outline: 0!important;
   /* I changed the color on this line */
   /* If you do not want any color, just delete */
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(39, 156, 136, 0.25);
}
```

Comment: this brakes accessibility

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```css
.accordion-button.collapsed::after {
  background: url("minus.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after {
  background: url("plus.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Changing “plus.svg, minus.svg” to file you need. Worth noting that the not(.collapsed) is turned 180 in the bootstrap CSS, so you could use the same SVG for both.